# Alternative to default_scope in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope, named-scope

I'm facing a problem with changing the functionality of an app and having to re-write about 700 method calls that now need to be scoped.

I've been looking into how `default_scope` works, and like most people I'm finding that it's close but not quite helpful for me, because I can't override it very easily.

What rails currently offers to override a default_scope is the `unscoped` method. The problem with `unscoped` is that it completely removes *all* scope, not just the default scope.

I'd really like some input from a Rails / ActiveRecord guru on some alternatives.

Given this basic desired functionality...

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...      
  belongs_to :user
  ...
  default_scope where(:foo => true)
  scope :baz, where(:baz => '123')
  scope :sans_foo, without_default.where(:foo=>true)
  ...
end
```

Could you / how could you create a method that could remove the default scope while leaving the other scoping intact? IE, currently if you use...

```
user.models.unscoped.where(something)
```

... it's the same as calling

```
Model.where(something)
```

Is it possible to define a method that would allow you to instead do something like this...

```
user.models.without_default.where(something)
```

...where the result would still be scoped to user but not include the default scope?

I'd very, very much appreciate any help or suggestions on how such a functionality might be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `with_exclusive_scope`.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/with_exclusive_scope/class

```
User.with_exclusive_scope do
  user.models.baz.where(something)
end
```

Comment: I thought that: a) this was deprecated, and b) this did the same thing as `unscoped` in Rails 3?